# Is there a shorthand for using the same variable being assigned for the argument in a function?

Tags: python, shorthand

Is there a quicker way to write this:

```
def foo():
    # What happens in here is irrelevant.
    return new_value

dict['i_dont_want_to_type_this_twice'] = foo(dict['i_dont_want_to_type_this_twice'])
```

Like when you use `x += 1`

Comment: `k = 'i_dont_want_to_type_this_twice'; d[k] = foo(d[k])`

Comment: You could define `key` beforehand and then use `key` instead of the long string.

Comment: I kinda wanted to avoid using two lines, but if there's no short-hand for this then two lines it is.

Comment: write a C extension, that directly modify the dict.

Comment: For limited types of values you use a `defaultdict` to modify the value with one `key` reference.  Numbers can be modified with `+=` , lists with `append` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any built-in or standard library feature for this. The most idiomatic thing to do is probably define your own wrapper function, such as

```
def transform(d, k, f):
    d[k] = f(d[k])
```

And then use it like so (note that I've renamed your `dict` to `mydict` to avoid masking the built-in):

```
transform(mydict, 'i_dont_want_to_type_this_twice', foo)
```

(I think `apply()` would make a decent name for this, but it's a built-in if you're using Python 2. Though it's been deprecated since 2.3, so there wouldn't be a lot of harm in it.)

Comment: Thanks! This is going to speed things up a lot for me. I didn't even realise you could pass a function into another function, interesting...

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, by using `update` on the dictionary.

```
d.update(a=foo(d.get('a', 0)))
```

Full demo:

```
d = {'a': 5}

def foo(val):
    val += 100
    return val

d.update(a=foo(d.get('a', 0)))

print(d) # outputs {'a': 105}
```

From the description of the dictionary `update` method:

- D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
- If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
- If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
- In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]

So, if the key exists, it will update it, and if it does not, it will create it.

Comment: This is probably as close as you get to '+=' with a dict. But still replicates the key name in the arg to `foo()` (which is omitted in your answer).

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Good call. I updated to include a closer representation of OP problem.

Comment: Am I missing something here? The key name is still written twice. `d.update(i_dont_want_to_write_this_twice=foo(d.get('i_dont_want_to_write_this_twice', 0)))`

Comment: @Michael No you're not. Looking over my solution, I'm realizing now that the key is actually being written twice. When I put together my solution I was avoiding simply doing d[a] = foo(d[a]). I'll see if I can think of anything else. But for now, this is all that is coming to mind. Apologies.

Comment: @idjaw Don't worry about it, if there was a common way to do this, (like +=) it would have been answered already. It is likely my method that is at fault, I should use shorter key names or stop being so lazy. Thanks though.

Comment: @Michael Good luck. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this for a one-liner assignment?

```
dict.update({key: foo(dict[key]) for key in ['i_dont_want_to_type_this_twice']})
```

Or, to update the entire dict:

```
dict = {k: foo(v) for k, v in dict.items()}
```